# Calling other functions within return of Angularjs Factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory:

```
.factory('PageType', function () {
   return{
     first: {
       firstFirst: {
         firstFirstFirst: this.second.secondFirst
       },
       firstSecond: "yoyo!"

     },
     second: {
        secondFirst: "hello!!!"
     }
   }
})
```

the `this.second.secondFirst` will not work, but `this.secondFirst` will work. How can I call the `second.secondFirst`? I tried `PageType.second.secondFirst` but that errored out.

Comment: Try without the 'this'. Factories are not new'ed up like services. Instead, the return value from your factory function is what's injected into your controller-in your case it's just an object literal.

Comment: Your example is either a poor abstraction of what you are trying to do or you are missing that assignment of primitives (i.e. a string) is by copy in Javascript so there is no value in trying to refer to `second.secondFirst` as it is the same as assigning the duplicate literal "hello!!!"

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reference the same value at two points in the object nesting? Why not assign it first to a variable before declaring the return object?

e.g.

```
myModule.factory('PageType', function () {
  secondFirst = "hello!!!";
  return {
    first: {
      firstFirst: {
        firstFirstFirst: secondFirst
      },
      firstSecond: "yoyo!"
    },
    second: {
      secondFirst: secondFirst
    }
  };
});
```

`this.second.secondFirst` and the like won't work because in that scope this refers to the anonymous function, (unless you wrap it in another anonymous function which is called as a method on the immediate parent object, however this object has no knowledge of the grandparent  object that references it as a value). `PageType.second.secondFirst` also won't work because there is no PageType in scope inside the factory definition (only inside the subsequent function scope where PageType is injected).

EDIT:

A variation on this solution would be to declare the object structure without the double references then add them in as a separate statement before returning the object.

```
PageType = {
  foo: {
  }
};
PageType.foo.bar = PageType.baz = "hello";
return PageType;
```

Comment: I did think about that but for the given situation, it's best if i keep it within the return or the whole json is removed from the return... which can be crazy.